# Scala how convert from Array to JSON format

Tags: arrays, json, scala, socket.io

I have to the code:

```
socket.emit("login",obj, new Ack {
         override def call(args: AnyRef*): Unit = {           
           println(args)
         }
       })
```

Console output

```
WrappedArray({"uid":989,"APILevel":5,"status":"ok"})
```

How to convert args from WrappedArray to JSON?

Comment: Using a json library?

Comment: Can example, please?

Comment: @pbezpal please read [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 1):

There are many json libraries. For example you can take a look at [Scala json parsers performance](https://github.com/yanns/scala-json-parsers-performance), to see the usage and performance. I'll demonstrate how that can be done using [play-json](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.8.x/ScalaJson). We need to first create a case class that represents your data model:

```
case class Model(uid: Int, APILevel: Int, status: String)
```

Now we need to create a formatter, on the [companion object](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/scala-book/companion-objects.html):

```
object Model {
  implicit val format: Format[Model] = Json.format[Model]
}
```

To create a [JsValue](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.8.x/api/scala/play/api/libs/json/JsValue.html) from it, you can:

```
val input: String = "{\"uid\":989,\"APILevel\":5,\"status\":\"ok\"}"
val json: JsValue = Json.parse(input)
```

and to convert it to the model:

```
val model: Model = json.as[Model]
```

A complete running example can be found at [Scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/toshetah/vJu6A1PwS5aXscx5EnCB2Q/4). Just don't forget to add play-json as a dependency, by adding the following to your `build.sbt`:

```
resolvers += "play-json" at "https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.typesafe.play/play-json"
libraryDependencies += "com.typesafe.play" %% "play-json" % "2.9.1"
```